# How can I download a pdf from firebase and access it from my app directory?

Tags: android, pdf, flutter, dart, download

I have an app in flutter which I am able to upload pdf into firebase storage successfully. I am able to fetch the respective url but when I click on it, it downloads outside of the app. This is not what I want, I would like to get the pdf download within the app. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help from [here](https://medium.com/@danaya/download-assets-dynamically-in-flutter-16c3472a65e5):

```
var dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
var req = await http.Client().get(Uri.parse(url));
var file = File('$dir/$filename');
return file.writeAsBytes(req.bodyBytes);
```